# Remove startup message to change Spark log level

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, log4j

I'm running Python scripts (and tests) with PySpark and want to remove irrelevant informations from logs.

Every time I launch those, I have the following message showing up in console :

> Setting default log level to "WARN".
>
> To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).

How can I remove it completly ? (ideally in **log4j.properties**)

---

### What I have tried already:

I have `log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, console` set in log4j.properties.

Doing `sc.setLogLevel(newLevel)` as the message says only work for the following logs and not at the beginning of the script.

Setting `log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=ERROR` in **log4j.properties** doesn't remove the message.

I have search a lot for this but can't find the relevant configuration.

---

From [Spark Github](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e1ea806b3075d279b5f08a29fe4c1ad6d3c4191a/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/internal/Logging.scala) (in Logging.scala), I can see that there is a `silent` variable for displaying the message but I can't find where it is changed:

```scala
if (!silent) {
  System.err.printf("Setting default log level to \"%s\".\n", replLevel)
  System.err.println("To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). " +
    "For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).")
}
```

---

Thanks in advance for any help,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution !

Just before the code I cited from [Logging.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e1ea806b3075d279b5f08a29fe4c1ad6d3c4191a/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/internal/Logging.scala), there is:

```
if (replLevel != rootLogger.getEffectiveLevel()) {
  if (!silent) {
     ...
  }
}
```

Which means that instead of trying to change the `silent` variable, it is possible to set log levels for `repl` and `root` logger to be differents in *log4j.properties* to achieve the same result:

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.Main=ERROR
```

You can also add `log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=ERROR` to remove other warnings from Spark that might show up.